# PayPal Donate, Are My Visitors Safe?

Tags: asp.net, security, paypal

I have little knowledge about ASP NET programming and I am using this to create a website. I am using the web forms template from visual studio 2012. I want to add a PayPal donate button, and I would like to know how secure my website will be just from using this template. And are my visitors safe when donating? I mean could my site get hacked and somehow my visitors get redirected to a fake pay screen?

I don't know what measures I should take to protect my site... I can guarentee you that it will have more traffic from capable hackers than your average website, how should I protect it?

I know this is a pretty broad question but I just need some starting points, and to know if a paypal donate button will be secure without any other security measures

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the question is broad, so this answer is also broad.

Lets clarify some things here.
When you are using PayPal to receive payments, the user is redirected to a PayPal secure website; that is the website will have the format of `https://www.paypal.com/...` which automatically withdraw some responsibilities in terms of security from your side, as you won't need to deal with the security of the payment.

A way someone can "crack" into your website, is also something to do with the server administration, if you use wrong file permissions, or poor passwords to your ftp, or you are using an out-dated version software is more likely that someone can crack into your server's file system and alter your source code.

ASP.NET itself is really secure, and does not allow you to expose into security traps that easy (roughly speaking), but keep in mind that nothing is secure enough.

From my side, I will suggest to you to have a look at the following:

- Server Administration awareness (file permissions etc)
- Prevent SQL Injection (if SQL is used in your website)
- Keep your server and it's software up-to-date.
- Use strong passwords for your FTP etc.
- Prevent [script attacks](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/request-validation)
- Validate all inputs, including cookies
- Be careful on how many information you are exposing to the outside world when it comes to the error messages!

You may also be interested reading [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdh19h94.aspx) site.
And as a final note, never trust your users and never assume anything when it comes to security or validation.

Comment: Haha never trust my user, thats pretty negative! Well okay Im hosting the website on my university's web server. So from what you're saying I can't really do much to secure my website with changing the server's configuration, is that right?

Comment: If you have access to the FTP, which you will, you have to be careful on directories permissions, have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions.

Comment: Thanks, I have another question, If I make a website from the "ASP.NET Web Forms" template in visual studio will it be as secure as creating a "ASP.NET Empty Website" template? The web forms template just seems safer because it generates all these extra folders and formats everything......
Thanks!

Comment: It depends. If you know what you are doing an empty template does not means that is less secure from web forms template. The best way to learn these details is actually to get your hands dirty.

Comment: Does this solve tour question? If so consider marking the answer as accepted or otherwise let us know so that we can help you further?